# Android NotificationCompat is not showing in jar

Tags: android, jar, android-notifications

Hi I used following code to show notifications.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_image)
                .setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setContentText("Test Notifications")
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setVibrate(new long[0]);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(10, builder.build());
```

It was showing correctly before creating .jar file. Once I create .jar and use it in another app means it is not showing. Can anybody help me to solve this?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notification has a small icon. if you make it to .jar file,it hasn't contain drawable resources. Please make it to .aar file and use it in another app.

Comment: Ok,thank you. But my customer needs only .jar. I try to explain him the problem. Thank you.